# script hash value, loss of one alphanumeric character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had to rename all of my .html files to .php so that I can use php gzip compression. Anyway the switch has broken one of my scripts. It's a script that loads in and animates content. It grabs the content from various pages and loads it into a container. That part of the script works fine.

When using the .html extension, the script will happily append the page being viewed to the URL, as in: www.site.com/#ABOUT

But now that I've renamed everything from .html to .php, there's always a missing letter, as in: www.site.com/#ABOU <--- missing a 'T'

Or, www.site.com/#CONTAC <--- missing a 'T'

www.site.com/#NEWSLETTE <--- missing an 'R'

Here's the part of the script that does this append function:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';  <--- .php (was: .html)
        $('#content').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});
```

What's up with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
href.substr(0,href.length-5)
```

Since your switch from .html to .php, you want

```
href.substr(0,href.length-4)
```

### .php is 1 character shorter than .html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to say this is the right way to do it, but changing this should work:

```
if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-4)){
    var toLoad = hash+'.php #content';  <--- .php (was: .html)
    $('#content').load(toLoad)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `href.substr(0,href.length-5)` was intended to remove `.html`, you might need to change it to `href.substr(0,href.length-4)` so it removes `.php`.